# How much RAM and CPU for a NTP server?

Tags: cpu, ram, ntp, ntpd, resources

As a side project, I am thinking about adding a NTP server to pool.ntp.org. I would like to use CentOS basic, but how much RAM and CPU should I assign to a machine that will only be running `ntpd` (plus all the basic OS services, of course)?

Comment: When you say "assign", do you mean as a virtual machine?

Comment: @derobert Correct, but I am wondering whether it might be a better idea to virtualize it or to use a Raspberry Pi. I guess it will depend on the answers I get :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the current state of timekeeping on VMs is (probably depends a lot on your hypervisor, too). `ntpd`'s resource requirements are minimal; I expect a Pi would be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run these services on a machine with 2x1GHz cores with 256MB RAM but I would expect that if this is your only service you have, you would only need something like dual-core 500MHz+ (one would work but needs to be a bit faster) CPU and 128MB RAM.